# 3D array with nans and detrending using scipy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter, nan

I have a 3D array but there are some nans in the first axis and my goal is to detrend the data.
I initially tried reshaping the 3D array into a 2D one, removing the nans and then detrending but then the shape of originally 3D array cannot be restored.

Would it make sense to replace all nans with zero (for example), detrend using scipy, and then replace all the zeros with np.nans?

Would that work properly with detrending a 3D array with nans?

This my code for doing it:

```
#(random 3d array with some nans)

arr = np.random.rand(27,100,100)
drops = np.random.rand(arr.shape[0])
arr[drops>.6] = np.nan # adding some random nans into 3d array

print(arr.shape)

# replacing nans with zeros

where_are_nans = np.isnan(arr)
arr[where_are_nans] = 0

#detrending with 3d array replaced nans with zeros

detrend_arr = signal.detrend(arr,axis=0)

#replacing detrended array's zeros back with nans
detrend_arr[detrend_arr == 0] = np.nan
```

Overall question is whether this would make sense to detrending a 3D array with nans (without changing the shape of the 3D array or removing nans)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no answers and problem is already solved